# Scrapy command takes 30 seconds to 1 minute

Tags: python, docker, scrapy

I run these commands inside a docker container on a remote server, but when I run `scrapy`, no matter what options or args, it takes so many times to show the result.

```sh
bash-4.4# time scrapy version
Scrapy 1.7.4

real    0m50.495s
user    0m1.397s
sys 0m0.111s

bash-4.4# time python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Oct 17 2019, 11:17:29) 
[GCC 6.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

real    0m1.738s
user    0m0.036s
sys 0m0.009s
```

Is there any one encounters a similar situation?

It doesn't happen in local machine or container

```sh
bash-4.4# time scrapy version
Scrapy 1.8.0

real    0m0.527s
user    0m0.503s
sys     0m0.024s
```

Here is the `Dockerfile`, which runs fine locally but remote server.

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine3.8

COPY docker/imagesPlugin/pip.conf /root/.pip/pip.conf

RUN set -x \
    && sed -i 's/dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/mirrors.aliyun.com/g' /etc/apk/repositories \
    && apk update \
    && apk --update add autoconf gcc make g++ openssh openssl-dev libffi-dev bash python3 python3-dev libmemcached-libs vim curl libxml2-dev libxslt-dev \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && pip3 install --no-cache-dir Scrapy \
```

Comment: Do you run the same image locally and on the remote server? Do you have the `Dockerfile` of that image running on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine locally, and they are using the same `Dockerfile`. I am trying to remove other things, running `scrapy` without other effects. Still the same. I will post the `Dockerfile`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's quite strange, indeed. I've tried on my laptop without any issue. However, I notice that the Scrapy version on your remote is **1.7.4** while the version in local is **1.8.0** (released two days ago). Worth to try to rebuild a newer version of your image and run it again on your remote to see what happens.

Comment: Maybe not related but, do you really need to start from `php-fpm` image? If you plan to run a Scrapy scraper on this container, it will be better to start directly from a Python image (e.g. `python:3.7-alpine`).

Comment: Thanks!   1) About the version of scrapy, I was thinking maybe this was caused by version, so I uninstall `1.8.0` install other version like `1.7.4`. 2) I didn't notice that, because this is a sub-project of a PHP project. Maybe I should try to use a more pure environment to try `scrapy` to see what's going on.  Thanks again for inspiring!

Comment: Keep us tuned ;)